# Spring Boot fully reactive Kafka processing

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-kafka, reactor

Is there any fully reactive, production ready Kafka support within Spring Boot ecosystem? By fully reactive I mean respecting backpressure / polling, concurrent message processing (flatMap) and handles possible failures (out of order processing errors). I did my research and there are several promising options (`spring-cloud-stream` with reactor based `spring-cloud-function` support, `spring-integration` with `KafkaMessageSource` and `Reactor Kafka` project), but I am not sure if they meet all the requirements and it is actually kinda confusing.